# How Runnable is created from Java8 lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I've come across some code which I'm struggling to understand despite a bit of reading.  There is a call to a method which takes in two args, one of which is a Runnable.  Rather than passing in a Runnable object though there is a lambda.

For example:

```
public class LambdaTest {

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    @Test
    public void createRunnableFromLambda() {
        Locker.runLocked(lock, () -> {
            System.out.println("hello world");
        });
    }

    public static class Locker {
        public static void runLocked(Lock lock, Runnable block) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                block.run();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, can you explain how a Runnable is created from the lambda, and also please could someone explain the syntax **()** -> {}.  Specifically, what do the () brackets mean?

thanks.

Comment: Tons of guides online for this. `() -> { }` The `()` represents the formal parameters for the method declared in the functional interface. `{ }` is the body for that method. `->` separates the parameters from the body.

Comment: If you are looking for answers emphasizing how RUNNABLE is created instead of syntax of lambda (as i did), I found this article helpful https://dzone.com/articles/how-lambdas-and-anonymous-inner-classesaic-work

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A Lambda can be used in any place where a functional interface is required.
A functional interface is any interface with a single abstract method.

The lambda syntax used in this case is `(arguments) -> {blockOfCodeOrExpression}`. The parenthesis can be omitted in the case of a single argument, and the braces can be omitted in the case of a single command or expression.

In other words, `() -> System.out.println("hello world");` is equivalent* here where a `Runnable` is expected to

```
 new Runnable(){      
   @Override
   public void run(){
     System.out.println("Hello world one!");
   }
 };
```

*(I'm pretty sure that it is not bytecode-equivalent, but is equivalent in terms of functionality)

Comment: A functional interface is any interface with a single **abstract** method. Since an `interface` may now contain `static` or `default` methods, that difference is important. To be even more specific, a functional interface has exactly one `abstract` method that does not override a method of `java.lang.Object`. Thus, [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Comparator.html) is a functional interface despite having two `abstract` methods as one overrides the method `boolean equals(Object obj)` of `java.lang.Object`. And it has lots of non-`abstract` methods…

Comment: Thanks @Pedro Affonso - so to answer my question, the () brackets are effectively saying there are no arguments being passed into the code block.

Comment: _almost_ equivalent, but one important difference is what happens if you use the keyword, `this` in the body.

Comment: also, if you decompile the code you'd see that it actually is constructing an anonymous class that implements the Runnable interface and pastes the code you wrote inside its run method.

Comment: *"The parenthesis can be omitted in the case of a single argument"* -- what is the **single argument** in `() -> System.out.println("hello world");`?